# Selenium Firefox webdrive, using Python, scrolling in div

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using python for a while, I want to save specific webpages which require prior login. Since this website uses javascript, I decided to use selenium for python with firefox webdrive. I was able to login. But the site requires me to accept EULA before I can access the required pages.

The problem is that I have to scroll down the entire text (with a seperate div scrollbar) before I can click accept. I am completely new to selenium and javascript.

The provided username and password are valid and I will change them once I get a solution.

```
dr = webdriver.Firefox()
dr.get("https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/user/programDetails.do?pgmNumber=1401611114")
dr.find_element_by_id("go_username").clear()
dr.find_element_by_id("go_username").send_keys("hajayd")
dr.find_element_by_id("go_password").clear()
dr.find_element_by_id("go_password").send_keys("123456")
dr.find_element_by_id("Image1").click()

dr.get("https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/eula.do")
# code to scroll down eula here
dr.find_element_by_id("agreeBtn").click()

dr.get("https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/user/programDetails.do?pgmNumber=1401611114")
# Final page I want to visit
```

Is it possible? Is there any other acceptable solution?

Comment: This is not duplicated question. This is not scrolling window to make a element visible, but scroll element's scrollbar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`WebDriver.execute_script`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) to execute javascript:

```
eula = dr.find_element_by_id('eulaFrame')
dr.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', eula)
```

Arguments (`eula` in above example) passed to javascript can be accessed using `arguments[..]`.

Side note: If you use `return` in the javascript code, that value is available as the return value of the `execute_script`.

Comment: I'm not an expert in JavaScript nor Selenium, but `arguments[0].scrollHeight` can be changed for a number. For example with 0 it scrolls the div up

Comment: This snippet is to scrolldown the div. how to scrollup the div?

Comment: @user3121891, Please post a separated question.