# How to scroll down one scroll down bar, if there are more

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

On my page, if there are more scroll down bars, how can I find the one I want to scroll down.

I mean, I want to scroll down the bar from the middle, the one from the right side is the browser bar.

As you can see in the below photo, I want to move the one with yellow arrows.

[image]

Comment: Try clicking on it first. Or dragging it. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833835/python-selenium-webdriver-drag-and-drop)

Comment: I'm trying now to see if I could scroll down the element found by class

Comment: Example I gave you uses `.find_element_by_name("...")`. Just switch it to `.find_element_by_class_name("your class")`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and I posted it, perhaps it will help someone.

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('paginated')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', element[0])
```

[Selenium Firefox webdrive, using Python, scrolling in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189431/selenium-firefox-webdrive-using-python-scrolling-in-div)